# System.Management.Automation.dll nuget package confusion

Tags: windows, powershell, nuget

I'm using System.Management.Automation.dll in my project and this file is being referenced from the following location: `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\1.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Management.Automation.dll`. It may seems like an older version of the powershell engine.

This file doesn't have any SHA1 or SHA256 signature. I'm trying to find a nuget package with digital signature and use it instead of copying the file.

I tried following nuget package but having build failures
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/6.2.3
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.3.ReferenceAssemblies/

What's the right way to do this? appreciate any suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: I hope the linked post answers all questions; let us know if it doesn't.